# Android: Identify with a unique number (01,02...60) a great number of Tablets

Tags: android, identifier

I have a great number of tablets (60-50) and I would like to assign each of them a number in order to maintain them, but what is the best method to do this?
I have thought of:
1. Using Bluetooth adapter and changing the bluetooth name for each Tablet (01, 02, 03)... However some tablets don't have this option and I can´t change the Bluetooth name.
2. Putting a XML file with the Tablet number in each Tablet and parse it to identify the Tablet.
3. Using an option lile Build.Serial in Android to get the Android ID. However I would like to know if there is another option which does not return the Android Id, which is so long.

Are there any options available, and which is the best option?

Thank you

Comment: get some labels and print the numbers on them, and then, STICK THEM to your devices' back

Comment: Hi, I've done this but apart from this I want to store this numbers in a database and not just physically

Comment: ID + IMEI pair them on an excel sheet should be an easy way

Comment: Thanksfor your help but I would like to know if it is possible to asign each Tablet a normal and short number (01, 02, 03, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use anyone above..please check the following links

[Getting Udid in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429916/getting-udid-in-android)

[Android unique UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754181/android-unique-udid)

hope this helps you!

Comment: As far as I know, the solutions you posted return a long number and I'm looking for a short normal number ( 01, 20, 40, 23..)

Comment: Then that's not possible by default,if you are using a db,then for the first time you need to assign a unique value as you said from 0-60 and use that from next time..